# Why doesn't my application behave the same when it's launched by systemd.service as when it's launched manually?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linux, systemctl

I've got a dotnet API running on my raspberry, when I lauch the executable manually, it listens on
`http://<raspberry_ip>:<custom-port>` as configured on my `appsettings.json` but when I use it as a service on my raspberry boot, it lauches on `http://localhost:5000`.

I know something must be missing in my `/lib/systemd/system/<app>.service` but I failed to see what.

My service configuration :

```
[Unit]
Description=Lauches API on boot
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/<user>/Dev/<app_executable>
User=<user>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It seems quite strange, is this because of the moment the service lauches (too soon?) or am I missing something else in my configuration ?

Thanks a lot.

Ps: I also tried to change `ExecStart` and provide my dotnet path like so :
`ExecStart = /<dotnet_path> /<app_path>.dll` but it didn't work either.

Comment: @SanchoPanza Thanks a lot for your answer, I will add it to my service and it seems quite logical too, but TheTanic's answer solved my issue, even if I'm sure your's prevented some problems ahead too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `WorkingDirectory` parameter.

According to the [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html):

> WorkingDirectory= 
> Takes a directory path relative to the service's root directory specified by RootDirectory=, or the special value "~". Sets the
> working directory for executed processes. If set to "~", the home
> directory of the user specified in User= is used. If not set, defaults
> to the root directory when systemd is running as a system instance and
> the respective user's home directory if run as user. If the setting is
> prefixed with the "-" character, a missing working directory is not
> considered fatal. If RootDirectory=/RootImage= is not set, then
> WorkingDirectory= is relative to the root of the system running the
> service manager. Note that setting this parameter might result in
> additional dependencies to be added to the unit (see above).

Comment: Oh my god, thanks a lot ! I overlooked this parameter, so sorry for this. Thanks a lot again for your answer !